# :nth-last-child(-n+3) doesn't work with article element?

Tags: css

I was wondering why `:nth-last-child(-n+3) {}` is not working for the article element inside my document markup? According to the comments it should work, like the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/8PXXm/

When I past the markup inside my layout, it doesn't work for me. I want to select the last 3 items in a row.

```
.post-entry:nth-last-child(n+3) { display: none; }
```

Above code selects all row items, not the last 3.

HTML:

```
<article class="grid_4 post-entry">
    <a href="#" title="">
        <figure class="post-thumb">
                <img src="../images/placehold.png" alt="Placehold">

                <figcaption>
                    <img src="../images/cross.png" alt="Cross x">
                </figcaption><!-- End figcaption.post-thumb -->
        </figure><!-- End figure.post-thumb -->
    </a>
</article><!-- End article.grid_4 post-entry -->
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4XP5W/11/

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: `Does :nth-last-child(-n+3) works with the article element?` - Yes it does (see [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8PXXm/)). As you can see in the [**w3org Spec on nth-last-child**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo) it does not mention that the `article` element is excluded from it's functionality. Your issue is most likely the CSS command itself in combination with the markup you have. If you post the relevant markup we can have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine you are just missing the `-` in your selector.

But it still not working?

You need to remove last two elements `div.clear` and `footer.grid_12` from your parent `div.container12`

Because:

> The :nth-last-child CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings after it in the document tree.

So your selector `.post-entry:nth-last-child(n+3) { background: red; }` is selecting

`div.clear` and `footer.grid_12` siblings.

**Edit:**

If you want to keep those elements in your HTML document, just wrap your `.post-entry` elements within any block element like `div`, `section` excluding the last two non siblings of `.post-entry`. So make sure the block element only contains siblings of `.post-entry`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4XP5W/13/)

Comment: Oke. I see it. When I remove above codes it will apply correctly on the last 3 elements of the article element. But both divs are important for my markup. Is it possible to fix that issue ? @RahilWazir